# using save-some-buffers to offer saving only the current buffer

Tags: elisp

In some elisp code I want to ask whether the user will save the current buffer before I proceed further.

For this, I can use `save-some-buffers` and pass an extra args to select only the current buffer, as in:

```
(let ((buff (current-buffer)))
  (save-some-buffers nil (function (lambda () (eq (current-buffer) buff)))))
```

Is there already an elisp function that does (more or less) the same thing? I'd rather use standard library functions than maintain my own code.

In particular, I like using `save-some-buffers` because it understands several answers and does more checks than I would do myself.

Comment: Slightly simpler, perhaps: `(save-some-buffers nil \`(lambda () (eq (current-buffer) ,(current-buffer))))`

Comment: A good impulse in general, I really wouldn't worry about it in this case -- if `(current-buffer)` ever breaks, so will the rest of Emacs.

Comment: What I am afraid might break is `save-some-buffers`. Its optional parameters are not that clear, and their specification + order + number + ... may change in the future.